# Postman output "status":404,"error":"Not Found","path":"/api/employees"

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, rest, postman

The spring boot REST app with MySQL.

I am trying to add record to a database and expect the record added and postman got it as output instead of the output:

> "status":404,"error":"Not Found","path":"/api/employees"

Following is the classes:

```
package com.controller;      

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;       
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;      
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;     
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;       
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;      
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;       

import com.service.EmployeeService;       
import com.model.Employee;       


@RestController      
@RequestMapping("/api")     
public class EmployeeController {      

    private EmployeeService employeeservice;      

    public EmployeeController(EmployeeService employeeservice) {     
        super();     
        this.employeeservice = employeeservice;     
    }       

    //build create Employee REST API     
    @PostMapping("/employees")    
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> saveEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee)    
    {     
        return new ResponseEntity<Employee>(employeeservice.saveEmployee(employee),     HttpStatus.CREATED);     
        
    }         
    
}
      
package com;      

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;       
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;      

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;      


@EnableJpaRepositories(     
        basePackages = {"com.model"})     
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"service.impl"})     


public class RestapimysqlApplication {     

    public static void main(String[] args) {      
        SpringApplication.run(RestapimysqlApplication.class, args);      
    }     

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you're scanning the package that contains your REST controller (i.e. com.controller), seems like you're only scanning the service.impl package on your RestapimysqlApplication class.

You should probably add the com.controller to the list of packages being scanned by Spring here:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.repository"})
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"service.impl", "com"})
@EntityScan({"com.model"})
public class RestapimysqlApplication {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Seems it didn't scan the EmployeeService class (which I assume you have annotated as either `@Component` or `@Service`) therefore could not create a bean off of that class, you could probably change the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation to be: `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"service.impl", "com"})` so that all packages under the com package are scanned.

Comment: package com.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;


import com.model.Employee;


public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee,Long>   {

}

Comment: I got this error Parameter 0 of constructor in com.service.impl.EmployeeServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.repository.EmployeeRepository' that could not be found.
following is the repository interface                                                                                                                             
 package com.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;


import com.model.Employee;


public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee,Long>   {

}

Comment: Might need to change `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.model"})` to `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.repository"})` since it looks like your repositories are located inside the com.repository package and not com.model

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository' defined in com.repository.EmployeeRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on RestapimysqlApplication: Not a managed type: class com.model.Employee
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.model.Employee

Comment: Try this: `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.model", "com.repository"})`

Comment: Also, you might need to add `@EntityScan({"com.model"})` to the `RestapimysqlApplication` for Spring to pick up your models and treat them as managed entities for persistence purposes.

Comment: i got this error message  three time Not a managed type: class com.model.Employee

Comment: I've update my answer to include the `@EntityScan`, make sure the Employee class is annotated with the `@Entity` annotation from `javax.persistence.Entity`.

Comment: I was added @EntityScan to Employee class and added to RestapimysqlApplication after your comment but i got same error Not a managed type: class com.model.Employee

Comment: You're not supposed to add `@EntityScan` to the Employee class, only to the RestapimysqlApplication class. The Employee class should be annotated as `@Entity`

Comment: One more thing, I'm looking at your `package com.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import com.model.Employee;

public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee,Long> { }
` and it looks like it's missing the `@Repository` annotation

Comment: i got this warning error Unnecessary `@Repository`